# rails validates_associated if/unless not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a parent with a has_many association to children. The child class has some of its own validations. I only want the child validations to run if a value on the parent is set to true. For some reason, no matter what i try the validations on the child are always run.

**parent class**

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  validates_associated :children, if: Proc.new { |m| m.do_validation == true }

end
```

**child class**

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Am i using `validates_associated` incorrectly here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) is to perform validations on associated records, but in the context of the caller. In your example when you create `Parent` if all validations on `Parent` pass, then it will call validations on the `Child` ( all related children), and if some of those validations fail, the create of the `Parent` will fail.

This also means when you create `Child` it will call all validations on the `Child`, it does not mater that you have put `if` in the `Parent` class, because validations are related to the `Child` model.

To prevent validations of `Child` to be executed every time when record is `created, updated, ...` you have to add `if` clause in the `Child` model.